# Merging multiple excel files into a master file using python with out any repeated values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I have multiple excel files with different columns and some of them have same columns with additional data added as additional columns. I created a masterfile which contain all the column headers from each excel file and now I want to export data from individual excel files into the masterfile. Ideally, each row representing all the information about one single item.

I tried merging and concatenating the files, it adds all the data as new rows so, now I have some columns with repeated data but they also contain additional data in different columns.

What I want now is to recognize the columns that are already present and fill in the new data instead of repeating the all columns using python. I cannot share the data or the code so, looking for some help or idea to get this done. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example and/or show your input+expected output ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably merging the wrong way.
Not sure about your masterfile, sounds not very intuitive.

Make sure your rows have a specific ID that identifies it.
Then always perform the merge with that id and the 'inner' merge type.